# Insufficient Privileges error while clicking on any tab in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

After installing a managed package in salesforce I log in with another salesforce credentials, after that I clicked on custom pages and it shows Insufficient Privileges error.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Check whether your profile has the access to those tabs. Go to Name > My Profile > User Details and click on the profile. Check whether you have required access to those pages/ tabs

Answer (score 1):

While installing a managed package in salesforce just check all objects , settings and permissions before intalling and then install.Check whether tabs had access to ur profile , if u don't have permissions u will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the profile of the user have logged ino the org from. Your logged in profile must not be having permissions (access) to the managed package. This may be because at the time of installation you might not have given access to the profile you loggen in from

Answer (score 0):

If you can remember, during the App installation, it asked you who can use the App.

1. Admins Only
2. All Users
3. Specific Profiles...

If you have clicked next buttons until the Installation wizard completed then most probably than not, you have selected the default option which is Admins Only.

How to check and reconfigure this?

Click on Setup | Go to the Profile of the Affected User | Click on EDIT | Scroll Down to 'Custom App Settings' | Look for the App name and Put a tick on the Visible checkbox next to it | Click on Save

Now try to see if the User still have the same error when trying to click on the App Tab.

Hope this helps !